# IIS10 PHP 7.04 pass through and show everything

Tags: php7, custom-errors, debug

I'm using internet information server 10,and I have an error in php.
I can't debug using "echo", because IIS10 cancel all the html render if an error has been found.

PHP.ini:

```
cgifix_pathinfo=1
cgi_force_redirect=1
fastcgi.impersonate=1
log_errors=on
error_reporting E_all
```

website.config

```
errormode = detailed
existingresponse= passthrough
defaultresponsemode= execute url
```

Logs, show nothing.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure if you have added this into php.ini:

```
display_errors = On
```

and I'm not sure if settings in php.ini are case-sensitive, just in case change E_all to E_ALL (in errors_reporting value).

Comment: I did it, at the end I just used another PHP server.
IIS is the worst for php